# DLL miss in QGIS 2.99 version

Tags: qgis

I have install QGIS 2.99 version but I have dll error missed every time to try start it.
I try different ways to do that install `standalone` or via `OSGEO` but I have some error.

I use windows 10 64bit.

error message dll miss:

```
qgis_app.dll
qgis_analysis.dll
qgis_qui.dll
```

how to fix that ?is the bug of QGIS ?

Comment: As you are using the developer version it would be nice if you check the bug tracker and probably write a bug report. Therefore this version is meant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to an unrelease dev version and should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.